# What hook do I use if I want to update a user profile field when a new user is created?

Tags: hooks, profiles

What hook do I use if I want to update a user profile field when a new user is created?

```
function default_followers() {
// set default follower 

    $current_id = get_current_user_id();
    $key   = 'followers';
    $value  = '1';


    update_user_meta( $current_id, $key, $value);
}

add_action('????????????????', 'default_followers' );
```

Ive tried: personal_options_update

Ive tried: edit_user_profile_update

Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the `user_register` hook, which fires immediately after the new user's username and (hashed) password are saved to the DB.